# Use an abstract value in a superclass constructor in Kotlin

Tags: oop, kotlin, inheritance, abstract-class

I have an abstract class in Kotlin that has an abstract field:

```
abstract val maxSemitoneDistance: Float
```

and I have two classes that extend from this abstract class and override this value, defining it, for example:

```
override val maxSemitoneDistance = 1f
```

I need to use this value on the parent class' constructor, which should be fine as during runtime it will have been defined by the child classes. But when I try to use it, the value is always 0! What is going on here? I tried changing it to an abstract method and implementing it instead with the same effect, getting 0 instead of the real overriden value.

Comment: Instead of making it `abstract`, put it in the primary constructor.

Answer (score 1):

> I need to use this value on the parent class' constructor, which should be fine as during runtime it will have been defined by the child classes.

It is initialized in the constructor of the child class, which only runs *after* the constructor of the parent class (which makes sense because the fields of child class can depend on values from the parent).

> I tried changing it to an abstract method and implementing it instead with the same effect, getting 0 instead of the real overriden value.

This should work however. Assuming you do

```
// superclass
abstract fun maxSemitoneDistance(): Float

// subclass
override fun maxSemitoneDistance() = 1f
```

And so should

```
override val maxSemitoneDistance get() = 1f
```

But basically, be very careful about using any virtual functions or properties in the constructor, abstract or not.